# SQL, GETDATE in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use my query as the current day for my SQL query.

What I am trying below returns 0 records:

```
select * 
from [TEST].[dbo].LIMIT 
where endOfDay = GETDATE()

select * 
from [TEST].[dbo].LIMIT 
where endOfDay = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

where endOfDay >= getdate() and endOfDay < getdate() + 1
```

An example date would be `2019-07-09 00:00:00.0`

Also if there is no given date for today's date can I get a range of dates?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of endOfDay?

Comment: GetDate() is a precise value... right down to milliseconds.  It is unlikely endOfDay would ever match..   You need to clarify what endOfDay is.  Is it a date or datetime?

Comment: for example a date will be `2019-07-09 00:00:00.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using quotes makes it looking for a meaningless literal `'GETDATE()'` to find nothing

You can use

```
with LIMIT(today, EndOfDay) as
( 
select CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())), GETDATE()
)
select EndOfDay 
  from LIMIT 
 where EndOfDay >= today and EndOfDay < today + 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=94c94ab1aaae85cf89bfb5ea78e8f11c)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt seem to return anything either. Perhaps I have no data on this date, can I subtract a day or two?

Comment: This should give a range of dates right? Not sure, nothing is returning but the query is being executed.

Comment: WHOA its working!! Can you explain this? Can you Select all on this?

Comment: @excelguy `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))` returns current date and time, and `GETDATE()` returns only current day. Here we're looking for the interval for current day.

Comment: @excelguy nothing, just a standard traditional adornment :)

Comment: when i remove `id` i get an error that my LIMIT  has more columns that were specified in the column list

Comment: @excelguy since, you need to remove `1,`(inside the subquery) also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196341/discussion-between-excelguy-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to omit the quotes or else 'GETDATE()' is just a string.

Second, to match by "day", you need to strip the time part from the result of `GETDATE()`, which you can do by using `CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)` instead:

```
select *
from [TEST].[dbo].LIMIT
where endOfDay = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

For this to work best, the `endOfDay` column also needs to be of type `DATE`. If it is something else, you need to also CAST or CONVERT `endOfDay` to a `DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * 
from [TEST].[dbo].LIMIT 
where cast(endOfDay as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/50624) to see what the date will be compared with.

Comment: @excelguy: Please check the sql fiddle link to see the comparison.

Comment: hmm for smoe reason my database is giving me an incorrect syntax near =

Comment: @excelguy: Please check the query you have tried in your system. Did you miss any paranthesis? Also, it is a good way to cast the date field also, it will make sure that there are no hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: okay syntax error was on my side. Cant seem to get it to return any records though.

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` returns the server's current date *and time*.  Unless you have any records that match that exactly, it doesn't make sense to use `GETDATE`.  It doesn't look like you do based on the `endOfDay` column name.

The other criteria you show,
`dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0)` is essentially stripping the time off and returning midnight of the current date.

```
select getdate()                                2019-07-11 15:10:09.287
select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0)   2019-07-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why not simply  convert(date,getdate())  ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti backwards compatibility - DATE was added in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti that would work too, I was just trying to explain the differences the way the OP had asked it.

Comment: @ScottHoffman I get that,  I just seemed an odd route go go  :)

Comment: @DStanley Bit of a reach, but I'll buy it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about time, convert both EndofDay and Getdate to a simple date for comparison.

```
select * from [TEST].[dbo].LIMIT where convert(date,EndOfDay) = convert(date,getdate())
```

Comment: @excelguy OK - no one can really help if you can't provide useful feedback and you provide a single example for a date that is irrelevant. Help others help you. If you don't have tsql skills, let people know so that explanations and discussions provide appropriate details. So post the results (in your original question) of this query: select top 5 * from Test.dbo.LIMIT order by endOfDay desc;